# How do I get rid of a polyfill in vite's build outout? (solved)

Tags: vite

my build output starts with

```
(function polyfill() {
  const relList = document.createElement("link").relList;
  if (relList && relList.supports && relList.supports("modulepreload")) {
    return;
  }
  for (const link of document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="modulepreload"]')) {
    processPreload(link);

...

    return fetchOpts;
  }
  function processPreload(link) {
    if (link.ep)
      return;
    link.ep = true;
    const fetchOpts = getFetchOpts(link);
    fetch(link.href, fetchOpts);
  }
})();
```

my vite.config is

```
export default {
    esbuild: {
        ignoreAnnotations: true
    },
    plugins: [
        jmxplugin()
    ],
    build: {
        minify: false,
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                entryFileNames: `app.js`,
                assetFileNames: `[name].[ext]`
            }
        },
        plugins:[]
    },
}
```

Where does that polyfill come from and - mainly relevant - how can I get rid of that in the build output?

I found

```
https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-modulepreload
```

and set

```
...
    build: {
        minify: false,
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                entryFileNames: `app.js`,
                assetFileNames: `[name].[ext]`
            }
        },
        plugins:[],
        modulePreload: false
    },
}
```

but that did not fix it. Still have this polyfill in the output.

finally got it:

```
polyfillModulePreload: false
```

https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-polyfillmodulepreload